# Split up urlstring in php

Tags: php, parsing, url, post, get

I am working with a payment provider. After somebody has bought something, the data of the transaction is sent to my **api.php**. The details are encoded so I decode them with a function of the payment provider. The *get* parameter is `"o"`. But when I get it - it looks like that:

```
6e6eeb5a19ab4ab72e456ed325e7c732single100OK4917668157533262-07119519DEE0715DD708E6B65BC2412E1A8EE571F
```

I know the first value, the numbers are the transcation id. The "single" is singlepayment.The "100" is for "statuscode" for a successful payment, the other stuff I dont know but the last after the dash (*-*)is the user id.

How can I split the string to work with the infos? I want to get the statuscode and the user id. In the papers of the api of the paymentprovider there are the parameters like "statuscode" or the "user id", but when I try to catch it with  `$_GET["statuscode"];` or  `$_GET["userid"]`; it doesn't work. Only `$urlstring = $_GET["o"];` works, but that's the whole string like I posted above.

Here is my api.php:

```
<?php


function decode($password,$encrypted,$salt){   
Bla bla bla
return $return; 
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST');
$urlstring = $_GET["o"]; 
$password = "blabla"; 
$salt = "blabla";
$result = decode($password,$urlstring,$salt); 
$file = 'file.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $result);
?>
```

The writing of the data in file is only for testing if its working.

Comment: If it is an open API you should specify what it is so that it is easier to help you. Otherwise I think your question is a bad idea in term of security for you application ...

Comment: i just called the file api.php - its not really an api. I just want to get the parameters and do things with it but its in one string.

Comment: Why you are checking whether `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is equal to `'POST'` and trying to use GET parameters (`$_GET["statuscode"];`)? Try to dump all the post data `var_dump($_POST);` to check the presence of your POST parameters.